# C++11 attributes stored with debug information?

Tags: c++11, compiler-construction, attributes, g++, debug-symbols

Its a bit of an odd question.. Does anyone know if g++ 4.8 and above stores C++11 attributes with debug symbols ?

I'm thinking about writing a g++ plugin to add "user defined attributes" to g++ and was looking for example code showing the "tried and true" way to extract attributes from the g++ ast.

Sorry for the general question, I was having trouble tracking down the specific function in the gnu compiler source.

I'm asking the question to help decide whether to keep looking or starting new.

Comment: I can only say that it neither puts implementation-defined nor user-defined attributes into the debug symbols. Of course, it doesn't mean that you cannot modify the source of the compiler to make it happen.

Comment: Thanks Ali, I was wondering if any mechanism was in place. The purpose is to provide annotation 'like' capabilities during run-time, found in java and other modern languages.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it neither puts implementation-defined nor user-defined attributes into the debug symbols. Of course, it doesn't mean that you cannot modify the source of the compiler to make it happen.

Perhaps [this](http://stephanfr.com/2013/05/19/building-gcc-plugins-part-1-c-11-generalized-attributes/) may be of interest to you.